# Access 2013 UPDATE query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Hey im learning Access 2013 and im trying to build a update query if a specific number is found, i have made it so that i works for one number but i have more identifiering numbers that need to be updated in the same query and i don´t know how to manage that.

This is my `SQL` and the numbers underneath are the numbers i want to identify and turn to either `REQUEST` or `RESPONSE`, the identifying number is always at char 6 and 2 long `("MsgString",6,2)`

```
    UPDATE tblMsgs SET tblMsgs.MsgType = IIf(Mid("MsgString",6,2)="22","RESPONSE","REQUEST")
    WHERE (((Mid([MsgString],6,2))="22" Or (Mid([MsgString],6,2))="14"));

   if 19 = REQUEST
   if 59 = RESPONSE
   if 22 = REQUEST
   if 62 = RESPONSE
   if 14 = REQUEST
   if 54 = RESPONSE
   if 2F = REQUEST
   if 6F = RESPONSE
   if 7E = REQUEST
```

I have now made one query for each numbers and that´s not good (ineffective!) , is there a way to do all this in the same query? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `OR` in your `IIf`:

```sql
UPDATE tblMsgs SET tblMsgs.MsgType = 
    IIf(Mid("MsgString",6,2)="22" OR Mid("MsgString",6,2)="59" OR ..., "RESPONSE", "REQUEST")
WHERE ...
```

But it would be more straightforward and better readable to do this in two queries, one for "RESPONSE" and one for "REQUEST".

You can also use [the `IN` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208859(v=office.12).aspx) to specify a list of values.

```sql
UPDATE tblMsgs SET tblMsgs.MsgType = "RESPONSE"
WHERE Mid([MsgString],6,2) IN ("22", "59", "62", ...)

UPDATE tblMsgs SET tblMsgs.MsgType = "REQUEST"
WHERE Mid([MsgString],6,2) IN ("14", "19", "22", ...)
```

(your list seems to have errors, "22" is defined for both)

Comment: Thank you! two queries was better now that i se it! did not know about "IN" function and now it works perfect!

Comment: Just a side question, you don´t happen to know how this would be translated into python 3.6 syntax so that i works? i just get syntax error when i compile...

Comment: No, no idea. But if you execute SQL in Python, it would be the same SQL command. Maybe replace the double quotes " with single quotes ' if they cause problems. @sesar